# How to make jQuery sorting work with more characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script to sort with data attribute

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <div>
      <button id="sort" type="button">Sort</button>
    </div>

<li class="items" data-sort="1111111111.1111145000">2</li>
<li class="items" data-sort="1111111111.1111144000">1</li>

</ul>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var $wrapper = $('#list');

  $( "#sort" ).click(function() {
      $wrapper.find('.items').sort(function (a, b) {
      return +a.getAttribute('data-sort') - +b.getAttribute('data-sort');
      })
      .appendTo( $wrapper );
  });

});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vnk91or8/1/

The problem is that it seems that the maximum number of characters that can be sorted is 21. As soon as I remove one of the digits from data-sort attribute in this example, everything works.

My script sometimes generates more than that, 22-25 characters and that's something I can't change. Is there a way to make this work with more characters?

Comment: Always same type of number [1-15].[1-15]?

Comment: Yes, always separated with a dot, but sometimes it might happen that number of digits before and after decimal point is different. E. g. [11].[12]

Comment: Can you try with fix your decimal points by using 
a.getAttribute('data-sort')).toFixed(2)

that might solve your problem to not increase the number of characters.

Comment: @Loading.. Unfortunately not. They have to be that way.

Comment: You can do that in jQuery side, what's the problem with that

Comment: You should sort it alphabetically: `return a.getAttribute('data-sort') > b.getAttribute('data-sort')`

Comment: It's not that I don't know how to round numbers or reduce number of digits. The thing is that this is not an actual number, but complex number generated from multiple numbers, i. e. it has to be in this format.

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you, that works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you split numbers and than compare, this way:

```js
var $wrapper = $('#list');
$("#sort").click(function() {
    $wrapper.find('.items').sort(function(a, b) {
        var splitA = $(a).data('sort').split('.');
        var splitB = $(b).data('sort').split('.');
        return splitA[0] == splitB[0] ? splitA[1] - splitB[1] : splitA[0] - splitB[0];
    }).appendTo($wrapper);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
    <li class="items" data-sort="1111111111.1111145000">2</li>
    <li class="items" data-sort="1111111111.1111144000">1</li>
</ul>
<div>
    <button id="sort" type="button">Sort</button>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29pro65z/)

Comment: Nice out of the box thinking.